# How to check element level difference of 2 dataframes in r?

Tags: r

`> all.equal(df,df2)
[1] "Component “q09”: Mean relative difference: 1.82404"`
There is only one column `q09` differ in `df`,`df2`.Next setp, I need to find which row of `q09` is different and what's the difference.
I read similar question, `anti_join` can only find row difference.
As to find each element difference, how to do it?

Comment: `df$q09 == df2$q09` (assuming same length and order). Also `which(df$q09 != df2$q09)` to find elements that differ. or wrap in `sum` to count the number of differing rows. Maybe `?setdiff` for unordered sets.

Comment: suppose we don't know whether only `q09` column is differ. How to check element level difference?

Comment: This is pretty broad. However, you can check variable by variable like `lapply(names(df), function(x) df[, x] == df2[, x])` or replace that with `all` or `which` like `which(df[, x] == df2[, x])`.

Answer (score 0):

@lmo is right. To give a reproducible example for the OP

```
df <- data.frame (
  q09 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,7)
)

df2 <- data.frame (
  q09 = c(0,1,2.5,3,4,5,6)
)
```

you get the indexes with

```
which(df != df2)
```

that gives you

```
[1] 3 7
```

Comment: If there's not only `q09` column in df,`which(df != df2)` will give you strange result like ` [1] 26497 26498 26499 26500 26501 26502 26503 26504 26505`

Comment: True. Thanks for pointing that out. It was just a reproducible example, but in general you are right.